# Can you "restart" the current iteration of a Python loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

Is there a way to implement something like this:

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        something
    except:
        restart iteration
```

Comment: You can skip to the *next* iteration, but you cannot *retry* the current iteration.

Comment: Yep, it's called an inner loop.

Comment: you mean like `redo` in perl? I think there is no such thing in python.

Comment: I think they should add in general to program languages the ability to go back to the start of the loop on the same iteration (like they made continue and break, they should develop "reiterate"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could put your `try/except` block in another loop and then break when it succeeds:

```
for row in rows:
    while True:
        try:
            something
            break
        except Exception: # Try to catch something more specific
            pass
```

Comment: wouldn't the "pass" cause the for loop to continue?

Comment: No, because it is inside the while loop.  The code will just fall of the end of the `except` block and loop back to the top of the `while` loop.  Note that you could also use `continue` if you want.

Comment: So I would put this before the actual meat of my for loop, and it simply runs until "something" is confirmed to pass, and then it runs the actual "something" in my for loop?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  In the above example, you would replace `something` with the code you want to confirm to pass.  The rest of your code will go under the while loop and will not be reached until the while loop exits.

Comment: But this would just loop the while forever, but not restart the for loop. I think the question was if the for loop could just be repeated.

Comment: @Olaf - In the title of the question, the OP said he wanted to restart the *current* iteration, not all of them.

Comment: The point is the break. Break is reached each time, when something is successfull (don't error). Break breaks out of the dummy while loop. If something errors, it reach exception, and pass will reiterate another loop in the while loop (does not break the while loop), so it will retry the same iteration of rows, until succeed. Nice answer...

Answer (score 6):

You could make rows an iterator and only advance when there is no error.

```
it = iter(rows)  
row = next(it,"")
while row:
    try:
        something
        row = next(it,"")
    except:
       continue
```

On a side note, if you are not already I would catch specific error/errors in the except, you don't want to catch everything.

If you have Falsey values you could use object as the default value:

```
it = iter(rows)
row, at_end = next(it,""), object()
while row is not at_end:
    try:
        something
        row = next(it, at_end)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: This seems clearer to me than the `while True:` answers

Answer (score 3):

Although I wouldn't recommend that, the only way to do this is to make a While (True) Loop until it gets `something` Done.

Bear in mind the possibility of a infinite loop.

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        something
    except:
        flag = False
        while not flag:
            try: 
               something
               flag = True
            except:
               pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your for loop inside an infinite while loop. Check the condition where you want to restart the for loop with a if else condition and break the inner loop. have a if condition inside the while loop which is out side the for loop to break the while loop.
Like this:

```
    while True:
      for row in rows:
        if(condition)
        .....
        if(condition)
         break
   if(condition)
     break
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version without using nested loops, an infinite while loop, or mutating the original iterator. Also, it controls the number of attempts with a `max_retry` parameter:

```py
def do_something(retry=0, max_retry=4):
    print(f"retry: {retry}, max_retry: {max_retry}")
    try:
        raise Exception
    except Exception as e:
        if retry == max_retry:
            print(f"Max retries reached!")
        else:
            do_something(retry=retry + 1)

do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
it = iter(rows)
while True:
    try:
        something
        row = next(it)        
    except StopIteration:
        it = iter(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2¢, if `rows` is a list, you could do

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        something
    except:
        # Let's restart the current iteration
        rows.insert(rows.index(row), row)
        continue  # <-- will skip `something_else`, i.e will restart the loop.

    something_else
```

Also, other things being equal, for-loops are faster than while-loops in Python. <sup>That being said, performance is not a first order determinant in Python.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think user2555451's answer does it pretty well. That being said, you should use `continue` instead of `pass` as it will make sure the `while True` loop is restarted.

```py
for row in rows:
    while True:
        try:
            ...
            break
        except Exception:
            continue
```

I will explain it for newer Python users:

`break` only breaks the loop you're working in. So if you have something like this: (the variables and functions are imaginary)

```py
for x in imgWidth:
    for y in imgHeight:
         if ...:
             break
         drawPixel(x, y, "#FF0000")
```

and you somehow want to skip a pixel, you can `break` the loop as it will return to the previous level. The same is true for `continue`.

Now back to the example:

```py
for row in rows:
    while True:
        try:
            ...
            break
        except Exception:
            continue
```

You move any code you would like to run inside the `try` block. It will try to do it, and if it catches an error, it will retry because we `continue` the `while True` loop! When it finally does the code without errors, it `break`s and now it's back in the `for` loop. Then it continues to the next iteration as it has nothing left to do.