# For loop iteration with range restarting at index 1

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through a loop with a step of 2 indexes at the time and once it reaches the end to restart the same but from index 1 this time rather than zero.

I have already read different articles on stack like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776689/can-you-restart-the-current-iteration-of-a-python-loop) with a while loop workaround. However, I'm looking for an option which will simply use the element in my for loop with range and without using itertool or other libraries or a nested loop:

Here is my code:

```
j = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,9,11]
count = 0
for i in range(len(j)):
    if i >= len(j)/2:
        print(j[len(j)-i])
        count += 1
    else:
        count +=1
        print(j[i*2],i)
```

Here is the output:

```
0 0
1 1 
2 2
3 3
9 4 
2
2
1 
1
0
```

The loop does not start back from where is supposed to.
Here is the desired output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
9 4
0 5
1 6
2 7
3 8
11 9
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have to reformat the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by combining two `range()` calls like:

#### Code:

```
j = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 9, 11]
for i in (j[k] for k in 
          (list(range(0, len(j), 2)) + list(range(1, len(j), 2)))):
    print(i)
```

and using an itertools solution:

```
import itertools as it
for i in it.chain.from_iterable((it.islice(j, 0, len(j), 2),
                                 it.islice(j, 1, len(j), 2))):
    print(i)
```

#### Results:

```
0
1
2
3
9
0
1
2
3
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `itertools` solution:

```
import itertools as it


lst = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 9, 11]


a, b = it.tee(lst)
next(b)
for i, x in enumerate(it.islice(it.chain(a, b), None, None, 2)):
    print(x, i)
```

Output

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
9 4
0 5
1 6
2 7
3 8
11 9
```